# Extract large spacy vectors quickly in Python

Tags: python, numpy, spacy, bert-language-model, spacy-transformers

I am trying to extract some word vectors from a transformer-based model. The steps are:

1. Run text through pipleine using `nlp()`.
2. Break text into sentences (to be separately classified into binary categories).
3. Save sentence vectors to a list (to be pickled and used as model inputs once classification has occurred).

The actual model runs quickly enough, but (unlike with the skipgram vectors), the simple act of extracting the vectors from the `spacy.tokens.span.Span` object and saving them to a list or array object is very slow.

Here is a reproducible example:

```py
import spacy
import requests
import numpy as np
nlp = spacy.load('en_stsb_roberta_large') # from https://github.com/MartinoMensio/spacy-sentence-bert

# Get some random text
def get_text(
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erikthiem/pride-and-prejudice/master/starwars4.txt",
    num_chars = 10_000):

    response = requests.get(url)
    text = response.content.decode().replace("\n", "")
    text = text[0:num_chars]
    return text
```

Running the actual `nlp()` command takes very little time:

```py
# This takes 0.2 seconds to run
text = get_text()
doc = nlp(text)
sents = list(doc.sents) # doc.sents is a generator
```

However, if I want to save the vectors from the first sentence (36 words) to a list, it is extremely slow:

```
# Get vectors - takes 5 seconds
example_sent = sents[0]
sent_vectors = [word.vector for word in example_sent]
```

Obviously this does not scale well.

I do not understand why it is so slow, as if you run `type(example_sent[0].vector)`, it returns `numpy.ndarray`, i.e. not a generator, so the vector has already been computed.

Why does moving it from a span to a list take so long? The arrays are dimension `(1024,)` for each word, rather than `(300,)` for skip-gram vectors, which copy almost instantly. That is the only difference as far as I can tell.

I have also creating an empty array of the required dimensions (rather than a list), but that makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Although `example_sent[0].vector` returns a Numpy array, accessing to the field `vector` may perform a slow operation as well as the iteration over `example_sent`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard but `example_sent[0].vector` is not a method, it's just a instance variable, so I don't think it's performing any operation, unless I'm failing to understand how Python works. Good point about the iteration possibly being slow, but to test I just ran `[a for a in example_sent]` and that runs in 0.7 seconds, so that doesn't seem to be it...

Comment: Reading attributes in python can call user functions. Pandas is a good example for that: you can create a dataframe with a column called test and then read the values using `dataframe.test`. This will internally call a function of Pandas with a string "test" in parameter (and this is also pretty slow). SWIG also massively use this fancy feature. Python is a very-dynamic language (even built-in functions like `range`/`int` and class attributes can be redefined at runtime). Btw, how long is `example_sent = sents[0]`?

Comment: Ah I see! The source (https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tokens/span.pyx) does exactly that (line 498). It applies a a function stored in `self.doc.user_span_hooks["vector"]`, which calls the `sentence_bert` attribute defined in https://github.com/MartinoMensio/spacy-sentence-bert/blob/master/spacy_sentence_bert/language.py (line 10), which calls `model = SentenceBert.get_model(model_name); vector = model.encode([sent.text])[0]`. So it looks like it's reloading the model and generating the vector for each word, not just loading it. No wonder it's slow. Thanks for the help!